# Spring Boot - ControllerAdvice exceptionhandler not firing with put and patch requests

Tags: spring, validation, rest, spring-boot

Using the latest version of SpringBoot (1.1.3.RELEASE), I am trying out a very simple rest application. I have an exception handler to handle validation errors arising from bad input. The exception handler fires if I make a POST request. However, it is not firing if I have a patch or a put request. What might be going on?

The Exception handler class

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DataValidationExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ConstraintViolationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity handleBadInput(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

The main application class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The domain class

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Size(min=2, max=100)
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @URL
    private String website;

   //Not including getters and setters...
}
```

The repository class

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "companies", path = "companies")
public interface CompanyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Company, Long> {
}
```

This POST request is handled correctly. The website should be a URL, in this request it is not and therefore, it rightly generates a validation error and is handled by the exception handler: `curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -i -d '{"name":"comp1", "website":"www.comp1.com"}' http://localhost:8080/companies`

This PUT request is not handled by the exception handler, although it generates the same constraintviolationexception as the post request - `curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X PUT -i -d '{"name":"comp1", "website":"www.comp1.com"}' http://localhost:8080/companies/1`

What is going on?

---

Update. In the case of the POST request, there is no stack trace generated because the ExceptionHandler is taking over. In the case of the PUT request, here is the stack trace dumped

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.mycompany.domain.Company] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must be a valid URL', propertyPath=website, rootBeanClass=class com.mycompany.domain.Company, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreUpdate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
```

---

Update 2 - To troubleshoot, I added the a catch-all exception handler as well. For the PUT request, this catch-all gets to handle the exception instead of the one I was expecting (the handler for javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException). On looking in the debugger at what the exception is, the debugger shows this - `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SystemExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
    public ResponseEntity handleBadInput(Exception ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

So it seems like Spring is wrapping the exception for javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException into another exception. To see if the wrapped exception is handled correctly, I also added this handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class TransactionExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {TransactionSystemException.class})
    public ResponseEntity handleTxException(TransactionSystemException ex) {
        Throwable t = ex.getCause();
        if(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException){
           return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);    
        }else {
            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem though is that even the handler for TransactionSystemException.class is not getting to handle the exception. Its only the Exception.class is handler is getting to handle it. Mysterious.

---

Update 3 - I am at my wits end now. The exception handlers are just not being called correctly. My next test was to see if the database constraint violations are handled correctly. In the very simple Company model, the database is setup with a unique constraint on the company name. So if a violation occurs, the exception raised is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException. Neither the catch-all Exception.class handler nor the specific handler written for org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException are getting triggered. The json output from Boot is like this. WHAT???

```
{
  "cause" : {
    "cause" : {
      "cause" : {
        "cause" : null,
        "message" : "Duplicate entry 'comp1' for key 'chk_comp_name_unique'"
      },
      "message" : "Duplicate entry 'comp1' for key 'chk_comp_name_unique'"
    },
    "message" : "could not execute statement"
  },
  "message" : "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [chk_comp_name_unique]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the PUT call is generating the same exception? Have you seen it in the log or with a debugger?

Comment: Absolutely...in both cases, javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException. I will post the stack trace for the PUT. In the case of POST, no stack trace because exceptionhandler is triggered and I don't dump any stack trace there

Comment: Ok, waiting for the stacktrace :)

Comment: Does is make any difference if you change your exception handler to handle any exception?

Comment: I tried that out as well. And yes, it seems to be making a difference. I have a separate @ControllerAdvice class that handles any exception. For the put request, the exception handler for Exception.class is triggered. For the post request, the exception handler for javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException is getting fired.

Comment: That's interesting! Can you find out the exact type of the exception being caught in the case of `PUT`? It would give insight into was has happened

Comment: Could you show the complete stack trace? Probably your `ConstraintViolationException` gets wrapped into another.

Comment: I was just about to post that finding - the exception getting caught in the put is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException with a message "Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction". That may explain something. Spring is wrapping the validation exception around with a transactionexception, but stack trace seems to be dumped out before that happens

Comment: A PUT and POST are 2 different things. A POST leads to a new object that is getting persisted, a PUT and PATH will lead to the retrieval of an object which will be updated. This will also lead to different handling of exceptions I'm afraid. What probably also happens is that the Spring data rest [default `@ExceptionHandler`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/AbstractRepositoryRestController.java#L134) methods kick in before your `@ControllerAdvice` defined methods.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I guess you are right that Spring Data is hijacking the exceptions. I created a sample project and opened an issue with spring-boot to highlight the issue. A pull request is pending into the spring boot issues repo - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-issues

Comment: @sat, today 2016 this issue is the same (org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException  instead of ConstraintViolationException ). `I'm using springBootVersion = '1.3.5.RELEASE'` and my question is do I still need to create a custom @ControllerAdvice handler class?,  if you tested it with SpringBoot how did you added it to auto-configuration?

Comment: This question and your analysis helped me five years later, so thanks. The problem still seems to be outstanding in the most recent version of Spring/Spring Data/Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will be fixed in the next version of Spring Data Rest.
[jira-ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-421)

I see the code change in the github repo, so the fix would be available with SDR 2.3 RC1 (Fowler).